# Insert HTML attributes in VueJS Table

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, bootstrap-vue

How can we add html/boootstrap elements to a cell in vueJS

```
<b-table striped show-empty :items="filtered">
  <template slot="top-row" slot-scope="{ fields }">
    <td v-for="field in fields" :key="field.key">
      <input v-model="filters[field.key]" placeholder="Search">
    </td>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

[Screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLQhH.png)

Answer (score 0):

based on the documentation, there's a [custom data rendering](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering) for `b-table`. there will be 2 available options for this.

1. use templating for generating the table

```
<b-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
    <!-- this is only for generating progress -->
    <template v-slot:cell(progress)="data">
        <b-progress max="100" class="mb-3">
        <b-progress-bar variant="primary" :value="data.value"></b-progress-bar>
    </b-progress>

    <!-- for default value -->
    </template>
        <template v-slot:cell()="data">
        <i>{{ data.value }}</i>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

2. `v-html` approach. (not recommended, because it only supports *raw* **HTML** content)

```
<b-table :items="items">
    <template v-slot:cell(html)="data">
        <span v-html="data.value"></span>
    </template>
</b-table>
.
.
.
data: () = ({
    items: [
        {
            text: 'This is <i>escaped</i> content',
            html: '<div class="progress"><div role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="45" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width: 45%;">45</div></div>'
        }
    ]
})
```